# phpからyoutubeのアップロードに関して

Tags: php, youtube

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php?hl=ja#resumable_uploads
上記のURLを参考にして、phpでyoutubeに動画をアップロードするプログラムを作っているのですが、
必ずログインが必要だそうです。
そこで、ログイン無し（パスワードを教えずに）で、他人が自分のチャンネルに動画をアップロードできる方法は何かありますでしょうか。

詳しい方、ご教示下さい。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

YouTubeの利用規約に抵触しないかは別途、確認が必要だと思いますが、該当のサンプルコードの中で、$client->getAccessToken()という箇所で取得したaccess_tokenを別途、サーバに格納しておき、その値を使えば、access_tokenの有効期間のうちはAPIを利用可能です。

サンプルコードを、access_tokenを取得するまでと、access_tokenを取得してアップロードを実行するまでに分割して試してみてはいかがでしょう？